# Need to open a link(which is an entry in a table), retrieve/scrape data, go back to previous page, repeat in a loop using Python 3,selenium and xpaths

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

Im just starting out with selenium

```
new_tab_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="gridview"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[5]/b/a')
new_tab_url.click()
```

^ this is the line of code responsible for retrieving the link to the next page. The link is in the href of the anchor tag whose display text is "View". This "View" is the same for all entries in the table, the xpath, on the other hand is unique. I can open this link . But when I try to retrieve data from this new tab, using driver.find_element_by_xpath I get the following error,

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='District']/option[text()='Mumbai Suburban']"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.193)
```